# How do I set Symfony's env to prod via Scalingo's dashboard?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.1

### Description:

I attempted to deploy my symfony project on [Scalingo](http://www.scalingo.com), and got an error saying that

> [RuntimeException]
>   An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'"
>   command:
>   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to
>   load class "SensioGeneratorBundle" from namespace
>   "Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in
>   /build/205190f5c7174087665005026b4d9f8d/app/AppKernel.php:29

According to the scalingo devs, it's because I need to:

> You can update this variable via the dashboard:
>   https://my.scalingo.com/apps/websurg/variables or by using our
>   CLI : 'scalingo -a websurg env-set SYMFONY_ENV=prod'

I'd like to do this via the dashboard, but unsure how it works.

### Question:

How do I set Symfony's env to prod via Scalingo's dashboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SYMFONY_ENV variable is just a normal environment variable (like the ones you are using on linux).

To set it on your scalingo dashboard, click on your app, then go to "Environment" and in the text area add `SYMFONY_ENV=prod` to the other environment variables.

Then you'll need to click on the Update button and

- re-deploy your application (if this variable is needed for the deployment)

or

- just restart your application (if this variable is needed for the runtime).